# Mesh repair for 3D printing

Tags: modifiers

I apply a boolean modifier to cut a hole through a complex shape and it works fine but at the sides there are no faces for some reason, I followed every boolean tutorial so the boolean should work, I even tried decimating the mesh to see if it worked better with less poly. Does anyone know of a way to fill this all in with faces, it is made of two loops one ontop of the other, (im essentially trying to cut an somewhat circular face into my mesh, I also tried using netfabb but instead of filling in the sides it just refills in the entire hole the boolean was meant to make

[image]

Comment: I would say more information is needed. In case of questions regarding Boolean, this is usually a screenshot of a mesh before Boolean and a scheme of what you want to cut and how. In general all problems with Boolean come down to bad geometry (non-manifold / flipped normals / double vertices / z-figthing). There is some [dev work done on it](https://developer.blender.org/T67744) so that all above won't be that bad problems though for now it's in alpha mode

Comment: This occasional happens where the mesh is non manifold or has a geometry that causes problems to the boolean. The boolean can work but cant really deal with the geometry so it just delete it. I recommend o do voxel re-mesh before boolean, or at least check the geometry for problems like inverted normals and non manifold geometry.